# Kaplan-Meier asymptotics

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation

Following [pp. 36-39](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176347865) I have stucked with calculating covariance structure of the process
$$
Z(z) = Z_N(z) - \int _{(0, z)} Z_Y(y) d\Lambda (y),
$$
where $Z_N$ and $Z_Y$ are zero mean Gaussian processes and $\Lambda$ is some measure (p. 36) without "jumps" for simplicity (that is $\Delta \Lambda = 0$).

By Fubini's theorem: $\mathbb E Z(z) = \mathbb EZ_N(z) - \mathbb E\int _{(0, z)} Z_Y d\Lambda = 0 - \int _{(0,z)}\mathbb EZ_Y d\Lambda = 0$. Hence, 
$$
\mathrm{cov}[Z(s), Z(t)] = \mathbb E\left[ Z_N(s) - \int _{(0, s)} Z_Y d\Lambda \right]\left[Z_N(t) - \int _{(0, t)} Z_Y d\Lambda  \right]
$$
By direct calculation: $\mathbb E[Z_N(s)Z_N(t)] = Z_N(s\wedge t) - Z_N(s) Z_N(t)$.

> Please, give me an advise how can I deal with:
>   $$
> \mathbb E \left[\int _{(0, s)} Z_Y d\Lambda \int _{(0, t)} Z_Y d\Lambda \right]
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \mathbb E\left[ Z_N(s) \int _{(0, t)} Z_Y d\Lambda \right]
> $$
>   in order to obtain the final result?